# Xubuntu 16.04 - Move icons around the indicator

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, indicator, xfce-panel

I installed Xubntu 16.04 on my laptop and started customizing it to make it blend into environment.

Anyways I ran into one issue. How do I move the app indicator icons.

I tried the `ordering-override.keyfile` method but it hasn't worked out for me so far. I tried to google it for about 3 hours but did not find an answer. [Picture of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3KnU.png)

Comment: That image looks *really* like Windows 10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean these?:

[image: App indicators in the panel.]

**NOTE:** Before doing this, restart the Xfce panel with `xfce4-panel --restart` in a Terminal.

Here, I have a video that explains the process:

[image: Video explanation]

Or, text explanation:

*Right click any indicator* → *Properties*, which shall get you to this:

[image: App indicator preferences window.]

Where you can

- hide indicators by the ticking the checkbox that says *Hidden* next to the indicator
- move indicators by selecting one and clicking the up/down arrows next to them

#### Indicators scattered over the panel:

You can also have two or more *Indicator Plugin* areas, so that (for example) one area is in the middle showing the time, one at the end showing Network and Sound etc.

When moving a whole *Indicator Plugin* area, move them through the *Normal panel items* section listed above.

Comment: Unfortunately Steam and nm-applet do not show for me on that list as separate items, Instead they both are under the App Indicators option. [Here is what i mean](https://i.imgur.com/oQ9tUOF.png)

Comment: @Alcatraz Yeah, `nm-applet`, even in my video, moves along with the RecordMyDesktop indicator. Apparently, not customizable, see [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/33vu14/is_there_any_way_to_order_the_indicators_on/).

Comment: Great. Now i just need to find which icon does this wavelan plugin use. [How it looks now.](http://i.imgur.com/VdXk2FF.png)

Comment: @Alcatraz You mean that big green-bar thing?

Comment: Yup. Cant seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Never mind. The Wavelan plugin doesnt work. I'll make an activator that'll open `nmtui` in terminal.

Comment: Got it. This should do for now although it could look better. [Picture](http://i.imgur.com/ku4XemL.gifv)